# Get Nth character with Sed

Tags: string, sed

I'm in the middle of Playing Final Fantasy 7, and I'm at the part where you're in the Library at Shinra HQ and you have to write down the Nth letter--minus the spaces, where Nth is the number in front of the book's title--for every book that doesn't seem to belong in the current room, of which there are 4.

I need a sed script or other command-line to print the title of the book and get the `Nth` letter in its name.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need `sed` for that. You can use `bash` string substitution:

```
$ book="The Ancients in History"
$ book="${book// /}"   # Do global substition to remove spaces
$ echo "${book:13:1}"  # Start at position 13 indexed at 0 and print 1 character
H
```

Comment: is there a way to do that without storing the string to a variable, like `"The Ancients in History":13:1`?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do it:

```
echo "The Ancients in History" | sed -r 's/\s//g ; s/^(.{13})(.).*$/\2/'

=> H
```

**NOTE**
Sed starts counting at 0 instead of 1, so if you want the 14th letter, ask for the 13th one.

Here's it in a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [[ -n "$1" ]]; then # string 

    if [[ -n "$2" ]]; then # Nth 

        echo "Getting character" $[$2 - 1]

        export Nth=$[$2 - 1]

        echo "$1" | sed -r "s/\s//g ; s/^(.{$Nth})(.).*$/\2/";
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Perhaps what you mean is sed removes the first 13 letters and the next letter is the 14th.

Comment: @potong: Yup, I would have rather used the _print_ function-thingy, but I couldn't figure out how to get it to do what I wanted...